# Protecting OpenLayers from government shutdown

Tags: openlayers, geoserver

I'm new to OpenLayers and am working on an existing app.  It pulls together a few different layers over the same map, and one of the layers hits a USGS mapping service, StreamStats.  Thanks to the current government shutdown, the stream currently returns not map tiles but an HTML page reading "Due to the Federal government shutdown, usgs.gov and most associated web sites are unavailable."

The way we have it set up, we show a "now loading data..." popup and add StreamStats as a vector layer.  When it initializes we clear the popup.  However, because OpenLayers is only getting an HTML page back, it never seems to initialize and the popup just sits there.  How would I add an event handler to OpenLayers to better handle errors, in case a new layer gets non-useful data from a mapping service?

Here's a code snippet:

```
streamStatsKmlLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("StreamStats Basin", {
   projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
   strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
   protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
      url: sskmlurl,
      format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
         maxDepth: 0,
         extractStyles: true,
         extractAttributes: false
      })
   })
});
map.addLayer(streamStatsKmlLayer);
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use some other technology (jQuery ajax, servlet, ...) to probe a given map tile url (one of your choice) and analyse the result. Do not even run the OpenLayers code in case the result is HTML and show some message ?
Looks crazy to see those sites down at least they kept the vital ones alive...

Comment: Thanks -- I think I'm unclear on the timing aspect.  If I send an Ajax request I include a callback function for when it returns.  I'm not sure how to do that with OpenLayers so that I am notified that the tiles should be ready for evaluation.

Comment: You do it before you add this provider to the available providers. Make sure you have some fallback provider if that is possible.